# declaring more than one variable within a single auto statement

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Consider

```
auto x=foo(), y;
```

Is this legal? (I would imagine it is and implies that `y` is of the same type as `x`.)
While this particular example may not be very useful, consider

```
template<typename some_type>
void func(some_type const&x, some_type const&y)
{
  for(auto i=std::begin(x),j=std::begin(y); i!=std::end(x) && j!=std::end(y); ) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

Here, `i` and `j` are both of the same type (because both derive from the same type of operation on the same type of objects), so this seems perfectly safe and sensible, as it avoids to declare the appropriate type (which is best done using `decltype()`, i.e. via deduction again).

However, intel's compiler (version 14.0.1) warns me that

```
warning #3373: nonstandard use of "auto" to both deduce the type from an initializer and to announce a trailing return type
```

So, what should I make of this warning? Is there any problem that can come up with this type of usage of `auto`?

---

**edit** The simple code snipped above does indeed *not* trigger the warning. However, the code which does looks very similar:

```
struct Neighbour { ... };
typedef std::vector<Neighbour> NeighbourList;
NeighbourList const&A;
NeighbourList const&B;
...
const auto K = std::max(A.size(),B.size());
auto k = 0*K;
for(auto iA=A.begin(),iB=B.begin(); k!=K; ++k,++iA,++iB)
  ...
```

(the for loop lives inside a member method of a class template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is illegal: all declarators must have initialisers, and `y` doesn't.

The second is fine: both declarators have initialisers of the same type.

I've no idea what the warning is talking about: there are no trailing return types here. Neither GCC nor Clang give any warning about your code; I don't have an Intel compiler to test with.

Comment: I knew about gcc and clang. Also icpc 13.1.3 has no issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
auto x=foo(), y;
```

No it's illegal.

I can't reproduce your warning since both `i` and `j` have same type. That part is legal code.

Comment: A warning does not imply illegal code. Did you try with icpc 14.0.1? The previous version 13.1.3 doesn't complaint.

Answer (score 2):

According to the future C++ 2014

> ...shall appear as one of the decl-specifiers in the decl-specifier-seq
>   and the declspecifier- seq shall be followed by one or more
>   init-declarators, each of which shall have a non-empty initializer.

Comment: Why not cite the current standard, which has exactly the same wording?